# php array specified location to a new array

Tags: php

I had a json data

```
[
 {"s_month":"1", "s_name": "John"},
 {"s_month":"4", "s_name": "Merry"},
 {"s_month":"7", "s_name": "Apple"},
 {"s_month":"10", "s_name": "Kevin"}
]
```

I wanted according the month to create a array, but the array's length is 12, the array would like it.

```
Array(
 [0]=>John
 [1]=>non
 [2]=>non
 [3]=>Merry
 [4]=>non
 [5]=>non
 [6]=>Apple
 [7]=>non
 [8]=>non
 [9]=>Kevin
 [10]=>non
 [11]=>non
)
```

I must build a default 12 length array? How to do that? Thanks.

Comment: describe with more detail.

Comment: So what have you tried? What errors do you get?

Comment: Fill an array with "nons", loop through the actual values and set the appropriate indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array_fill(0, 12, 'non');

foreach (json_decode($json, true) as $entry) {
    $array[$entry['s_month'] - 1] = $entry['s_name'];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

try this,

```
$jsonStr = YOUR JSON STRING;
$dataArr = json_decode($jsonStr,true);
$newArr = array();
for($i=0;$i<12;$i++){
   if(!empty($dataArr[$i]["s_month"]) && $dataArr[$i]["s_month"]==($i+1)){
       $newArr[$i]=$dataArr[$i]["s_month"];
   }else{
       $newArr[$i]="NA";
   }
}
```